# Parse data to JSON using hash maps

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to convert the hexmaps into useable json code but I don't know really know how

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("user_id", userID );
    Map<String, String>  foodOrder = new HashMap<String, String>();
    foodOrder.put("id",productID);

    foodOrder.put("item_count",numberOfItems.getText().toString());

    params.put("product", foodOrder.toString());
    Arrays.deepToString(new JSONObject[]{new JSONObject(params)});

    return params;
}
```

It should look something like this:

```
{
  "user_id": 2,
  "product": {
      "id": 15,
      "item_count": 99
  }
}
```

But now I get this:

```
{
  "product": "{item_count=1, id=1}", 
  "user_id": "2"
}
```

I'm using the Volly library to pass the data form app to server.

Comment: `HashMap#toString()` _will not_ return JSON so put `foodOrder` directly as the value for `"product"`.

Comment: Why not using something like ```Map<String, Map<String, String>>```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toString() method will not return a json unless you have implemented it that way. In your case you are using hashMap's toString so it won't. 
Try converting the map to json string using Gson:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams()
{
   Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
   params.put("user_id", userID );
   Map<String, String>  foodOrder = new HashMap<String, String>();
   foodOrder.put("id",productID);
   foodOrder.put("item_count",numberOfItems.getText().toString());
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   params.put("product", gson.toJson(foodOrder));
   Arrays.deepToString(new JSONObject[]{new JSONObject(params)});
   return params;
 }
```

Comment: the the array look odd now {
        "product": "{\"item_count\":\"1\",\"id\":\"1\"}", 
        "user_id": "2"

Comment: How are you checking it? That should be because " is being escaped with \. Should be a valid json though.

Comment: i think it is working, it's the backend of my app that is not working properly

Comment: was just confused about the "/"